# cron expression with asterisk character included

Tags: bash, shell, rundeck

I have this code and I am trying to run on a remote node in Rundeck with input option as `0 * * * *`

```
#!/bin/bash
cron_expression="$1"
echo "Crontab expression: $cron_expression"
```

When I run this via the terminal it's working fine. Also, it works well when I execute it locally on Rundeck. But when I pass the same input and execute it on remote nodes in Rundeck, it's reading '*' as a wildcard character. The script file is on Rundeck server and reading from there. Can someone suggest how to run it on Rundeck remote nodes?

Comment: It not reading any input

Comment: You quote the input right? If you are passing `0 * * * *` it must be quoted to prevent *pathname-expansion*, e.g. `"0 * * * *"`. (it also must be quoted so the entire string constitutes one argument)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: I quoted with double quotes when its reading variable inside the script. But while passing in Rundeck option I simply entered as `0 * * * *`  and executed the job. Do i need to add quotes even in Rundeck option too?

Comment: Could you share the rundeck job definition to take a look? I'm suspecting that you need to use options to pass it to your script.

Comment: yes I am using options to pass input parameter. The job is working well when I execute it locally on Rundeck server. If I execute on remote nodes, then it using `*` as wildcard character.

Comment: Enough information to let someone else cause the problem themselves (in this case, the exact Rundeck definition you're using) _needs to be part of the question itself_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an [option](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-options.html#job-options) in your Rundeck job to pass it to your script (use the `@option.myoption@` format in inline-scripts steps or `$RD_OPTION_MYOPTION` format on "external scripts" steps). In that way, you can pass any value to your script. I left a [job definition](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/tutorial/terminology.html#job-definition) example tested on local and remote SSH nodes, this example uses your script as inline-script step. Take a look:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 11dec4c7-4514-42e3-baef-d777ba1294de
  loglevel: INFO
  name: TestCronString
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: .*
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: expression
    value: 0 * * * *
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |
        #!/bin/bash
        cron_expression="@option.expression@"
        echo "Crontab expression: $cron_expression"
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 11dec4c7-4514-42e3-baef-d777ba1294de
```

Check the result [here](https://imgur.com/26NZ5N9).

Comment: `cron_expression="@option.expression@"` implies that using `$(rm -rf ~)` inside the cron expression will cause that string to be executed as code. Does Rundeck have a configuration option that expects the substitution to be in an unquoted context and performs its own POSIX-compliant quoting or escaping? That would be considerably safer.

Comment: I used as command line argument `${option.expression}` and executed. I also tried `$RD_OPTION_MYOPTION` . It did not work even with this. Now I used this script content format to pass option to script `@option.expression@`. Its working now. Thanks